# Rails Create Not Creating a New Record in the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble adding things from my New Form to display in the Index properly. I don't think they're being added to the database but I can't figure out why.

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :coupons
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag coupons_path do %>
    <label>Coupon code:</label><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :'coupon[coupon_code]' %><br>
  
    <label>Store:</label><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :'coupon[store]' %><br>
  
    <%= submit_tag "Submit Coupon" %>

  <% end %>
```

Controller

```
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @coupons = Coupon.all
    end
    def show
        @coupon = Coupon.find(params[:id])
    end
    def new
    end

    def create
        @coupon = Coupon.new
        @coupon.coupon_code = params[:coupon_code]
        @coupon.store = params[:store]
        if @coupon.save
            redirect_to coupon_path(@coupon)
        else
            render :text => "Failed to create coupon"
        end
    end
end
```

My Index retains the new coupons but I think it only gets passed the id. It displays as /coupons/1 in an unordered list on the index page. Like-wise I can go to the show page but it only says "Coupon Code" and "Store," it doesn't include the data I passed it when I created it with the new form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `coupon_code` and `store` values are nested inside the `coupon` key since you're passing `'coupon[coupon_code]'` and `'coupon[store]'` as the field names to the `text_field_tag` method.

```rb
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @coupon = Coupon.new(coupon_params)
    # save coupon
  end

  private

  def coupon_params
    params.require(:coupon).permit(:coupon_code, :store)
  end
end
```